# My URL in Kotlin has an extra & at the end of it

Tags: dictionary, kotlin

```
private val BASE_URL = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?"
private var iTunesMap = mutableMapOf("term" to "parameter1",
                                                "media" to "parameter2")

fun URL.addParameters(map:Map<String,String>) : String {
    var newURL = BASE_URL
    for(parameter in iTunesMap.iterator())
    {
        newURL += parameter.key + "=" + parameter.value + "&"
    }
    return newURL
}
```

I am ending up with a & at the end of the URL.
How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Do you look for out of box solution? Why not removing & by hand before returning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it in a functional way:

```
val parameters = map.map { (key, value) -> // 1
    "$key=$value"                 // 2
}.joinToString("&")               // 3
return BASE_URL + parameters      // 4
```

Explenation:

1. We use map function with destructuring declaration of parameters `(key, value)` which correspond to key and value in each map entry
2. For each map entry we create string `key=value` ($ is indicator, that we want to use value of some variable - in that case we use value of parameter key and parameter value
3. After `.map` function we have collection of strings: `term=parameter1` and `media=parameter2`, we are joining them with `&` separator
4. Lastly we need to concatenate parameters to base url

If I can suggest - I would make this function more general by putting baseUrl as parameter - then you can use the same function for different urls.

### EDIT

---

As Михаил Нафталь suggested in his answer, you can add prefix to joinToString function so you don't have to concatenate parameters with base url. So after that improvement your code will look like this:

```
return map.map { (key, value) ->
    "$key=$value"
}.joinToString("&", prefix = BASE_URL )
```

Or you can do all of this using just joinToString function with giving transform function. (look for Михаил Нафталь answer)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner:

```kotlin
map.entries.joinToString(separator = "&", prefix = BASE_URL) { (key, value) -> "$key=$value" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable and `+=` involves copying the entire string into a new string. Do not use `+=` on a `var: String` in a loop, as that is O(*N*²); use a `StringBuilder` instead.

```kotlin
val urlBuilder = StringBuilder(BASE_URL)
iTunesMap.entries.joinTo(urlBuilder, separator = "&") { (key, value) ->
    "$key=$value"
}
return urlBuilder.toString()
```